# How to auto refresh a section of a page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a part of a page that has live data in it, I was thinking of just refreshing the page every couple of minutes, but that isn't right because of other elements of the page.

How can I do it? What language can I use to do this, what's easy to do and what isn't, what works well and what doesn't. Maybe some clear tutorials or even code examples.

I'd live to do this in something like PHP, but don't have a clue where to start, from a bit of research i see that Javascript and Ajax seem to be the standard for this but my knowledge of these languages aren't up to scratch.

Thanks for the time and help people.

Oh, the data that is being displayed is coming from a database if that's any help.

Thanks again.

Comment: You can use iFrame for that particular refresh.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a Javascript library such as jQuery and do something like the following simplified example:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  var interval = setInterval(refresh_box(), 60000);
  function refresh_box() {
    $("#myDiv").load('path/to/databasepage.php');
  }
} /*<= The closer ) bracket is missing in this line*/
```

and in your `path/to/databasepage.php` page you can have your select query and echo the results out.

What this does is sets a timeout to call a function (in this case, `refresh_box()` ) every 60 seconds (which is 60,000 miliseconds) and loads the data from `path/to/databasepage.php` in to your div with the id `myDiv`.

**edit:**

If you want to stop the auto-refresh you can bind an element to clear the interval by doing the following:

```
// assuming you have a clickable element 
// (typically a button or so) id called 'stop_refresh'
$("#stop_refresh").click(function(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: So this doesn't need anything like jquery.js??

Comment: Any chance of a bit of php to should the output? would i just show the ouput in the 'path/to/database.php' ? Or would it go back into the script and i would have to use innerhtml? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yes, you do need jQuery, as stated in the first line of the answer. You can find details on using jQuery on your own site at www.jquery.com

Also what the `$("#myDiv").load('path/to/databasepage.php');` does is essentially the same as innerHTML. Basically, it visits the page in the background and the page runs some code on your database which can return a set of results pulled from your database and displays it using `myDiv` as a _kind of_ frame around the page.

Comment: To illustrate this, you can change the contents of your `path/to/databasepage.php` to contain the following line `<?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?>`.

Next, set the interval to this: `var interval = setInterval(refresh_box(), 1000);` - This should  give you a good idea of how it works. You can also visit the page `path/to/databasepage.php` and press the refresh button - which is exactly what the `$("#myDiv").load(...` is doing, but the only difference is it is loading it in the `myDiv` container automagically. Simples.

Comment: I did a silly thing and im not proud, i forgot a closing ')' I'm sorry... hahaha One more problem though, for some reason its not refreshing the output, any ideas?

Comment: Okay i've got it now. The script you provided got my information to display but wouldn't refresh, so i found another scrip that wasn't far from here: http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2009/02/26/jquery-auto-refresh-div-every-x-seconds/           thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest method doesn't even involve PHP or JavaScript.  You can do it with an `<iframe>` in plain HTML.  The iframe loads an HTML or PHP page with the appropriate refresh header and it refreshes itself.

Main HTML page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   static content

    <iframe id='dynamic-content' src='refreshing.php' />
</body>
</html>
```

refreshing.php page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- refresh every 5 seconds -->
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
<body>
  dynamic content
</body>
</html>
```

Note that `<meta http-equiv="refresh">`  is discouraged for general refreshing a whole page, but it is pretty safe to use inside an iframe which must be constantly refreshing itself.

Comment: This is a fine option if the height of the iFrame doesn't need to be updated dynamically to reflect dynamic content within the iFrame.  If you know the fixed height or you can calculate it once and pass it to the parent page, it's all good.  But beware if you want an iFrame with dynamic/changing height.  CSS doesn't support that and the hassle of trying to develop around that big wide gap is a big bag of hurt and frustration.

Answer (score 3):

You cant really execute a live refresh for page components in PHP, AJAX is the most common means (Asynchronous Javascript And Xml)- which uses Javascript to poll other scripts (can be .php pages) which then return predefined output based on the request- this output can be content to inject into a page, or data which can then be interpreted by your page for another action.

In this instance, your .php page would include JS (javascript) in the head, whether linked or inline, which would contain details for launching an AJAX request- namely, how often or on what trigger (button press etc), by what means (POST or GET), what is sent (any other variables you wish), what the target script is (the script which will handle the request and output your required content/data), and what to do when the response is recieved (i.e. which element on the page should be updated with the response).

A little about AJAX:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/ajax/a/aa101705.htm

http://webtrends.about.com/od/web20/a/what-is-ajax.htm

Likely the simplest way to begin is to use a pre-existing Javascript library like the ubiquitous jQuery (jquery.com), there are thousands of tutorials out there for it, and though you will need to do some Javascript programming, the library has meant that you can rely on fairly simple syntax to do so (as simple as `$('#myelement').load('mypage.php')`):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/how-to-load-content-via-ajax-in-jquery/

In simple terms:

1. You have your php page with the element that needs updating (page A)
2. Build another php script which outputs the content you want 'refreshing', e.g. the latest news stories, each time it is run (page B)
3. Link to the jQuery library in your header section (page A)
4. Write a simple jquery function in the header section of page A, which says every X seconds/minutes, run an AJAX request to fetch the content of page B and insert into an element (DIV) within page A

Answer (score 0):

it's really a large question.

The most common way would be to use AJAX but you can also use a javascript database as [TaffyDB - The JavaScript Database](http://taffydb.com/) (never used it so i can't really speak about it).

Anyway, the easiest way would be to use JQUERY.