# Dynamically updating a web interface from a Python daemon

Tags: python, sockets, daemon

I'll briefly explain what I'm trying to achieve: We have a lot of servers behind ipvsadm VIPs (LVS load balancing) and we regularly move servers in/out of VIPs manually. To reduce risk (junior ops make mistakes...) I'd like to abstract it to a web interface.

I have a Python daemon which repeatedly runs "ipvsadm -l" to get a list of servers and statistics, then creates JSON from this output. What I'd now like to do is server this JSON, and have a web interface that can pass commands. For example, selecting a server in a web UI and pressing remove triggers an `ipvsadm -d <server>...` command. I'd also like the web UI to update every 10 seconds or so with the statistics from the list command.

My current Python daemon just outputs to a file. Should I somehow have this daemon also be a web server and serve its file and accept POST requests with command identifiers/arguments? Or a second daemon for the web UI? My only front end experience is with basic Bootstrap and jQuery usually backed by Laravel, so I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing this with sockets and some fancy JS modern-ism.

If there is a more appropriate place for this post, please move it if possible or let me know where to re-post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need fancy js application. To take the path of least resistance, I would create some extra application - if you like python, I recommend [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for this job. If you prefer php, then how about [slim](https://www.slimframework.com/)?

In your web application, if you want to make it fast and easy, you can even implement [ajax mechanism fetching results based on interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660528/how-to-auto-refresh-a-section-of-a-page) to refresh servers' data every 10 seconds. You will fetch it from json served by independent, already existing deamon.

Running commands clicked on Web UI can be done by your web application.

Your web application is something extra and I find it nice to be **separated** from deamon which fetch data about servers and save it as json. Anytime you can turn off the page, but all statistics will be still fetching and available for console users in json format.