# How to use AJAX to call a PHP Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a very simple PHP call from my main html file that is running the website. I have the following PHP file that uses Google's API to calculate travel time.

travelTime.php

```
$travelDetails = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins...;

$json = file_get_contents($travelDetails);

$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$time = $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];

echo "Your current travel time is $time";
```

This calculates the travel time from my house to work and I got it to display on the website using the following code in the body of the HTML code. This file is called info.php and it is running the html code and the whole website.

info.php

```
<body>

<h2><?php include 'travelTime.php'?></h2>

</body>
```

This calls travelTime.php and that echoes the information which displays it on the webpage. I am wondering how I can change this so I can have the PHP script called about every 10 minutes so the travel time stays up to date and changes with traffic. I know I have to use AJAX, but I'm confused on how I can call it and echo that information back to be displayed by HTML code.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto refresh a section of a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660528/how-to-auto-refresh-a-section-of-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery ajax() like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'travelTime.php',                        
        type: 'get',                                  
        data: {
            var1  :val1, // key value pair of variable : value
        },
        success: function(response){
            // Put the response to respective html
            $('#distance').html();
        }
    });
});

<h2 id="distance"></h2>
```

And to call it every X minute:

```
setInterval(function() {
  //your jQuery ajax code
}, 1000 * 60 * X); // where X is your every X minutes
```

Comment: It isn't displaying on my webpage. When I make those changes it just doesn't show up at all. I put the jquery ajax in <head>.

Answer (score 0):

if jquery is not included then you will get error
use this firstly

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

and then

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'travelTime.php',                        
        type: 'get',                                  
        data: {},
        success: function(response){
            console.log("Success  Response",response);
            $('#distance').html();
        },error:function(response){
            console.log("Error response",response);
            console.log("Error response Text",response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

If you still got stuck then click f12 and click on console and refresh .
Then comment here what are you getting there

Comment: Hi, I got that to return "Success Response" in the console. I'm just wondering how do i display that info in HTML? Do I call the #distance variable? Thanks