# Prevent Component reloading - AEM

Tags: aem

I have 2 pages in my web application. Lets say an home page and news feed page. When user clicks a hyperlink on home page then she/ he gets redirected to News feed page. I have 2 separate components in each page like

**Home Page** --- *Header Component* & *Home Page Details Component.*
**News Feed Page** --- *Header Component **&** News Feed Details Component.*

Both the pages has a common component Header. Can I prevent component reloading for the header component when users reaches the second page by clicking link on the first page.

By component reloading I mean the HTML code (HTL) code in the component should not be updated again with updated data instead for the second page, I just want to show the same data associated with header component in the first page.

Comment: Is your main goal to avoid reloading the same HTML in the browser or to avoid the rendering of the same HTML by AEM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of and related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660528/how-to-auto-refresh-a-section-of-a-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new page will always be loaded as a whole, because of just how [HTML] page loads work. What you are looking for is a [single page application](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). They are possible with AEM but are a pain to design, especially the authoring mode behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common HTML pattern and possible duplicate of related questions such as: [How to auto refresh a section of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660528/how-to-auto-refresh-a-section-of-a-page)

There are two general approaches, the first being far preferred and supported in various frameworks, all based on JavaScript (AJAX):

1. Break page into different DIV tags that are independently updated (header separate from body sections, each loaded via AJAX such that only part of the page that has changed is updated).
2. Use iFrames such that effectively there are different pages - each loaded separately from the other.